# Horizontal Line in Table Cell

Tags: tables

Why do the horizontal lines not appear in the first column?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\def\Vrulefill#1#2{
\leavevmode%
\hskip-.2in%
\leaders%
\vtop{\hsize=.0025in\vskip#1#2}%
\hfill%
\hskip.3in%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{C{2cm}cccclcr}
 Source                  & SS                    & df                           & MS                    & \hphantom{Nu}   & Number of obs & = & 250 \\
 \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.}   & \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.} & \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.}       & \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.} & \hphantom{Nu}   & F(5,94)       & = & 75.04\\
 Model                   & 7955693.156           & 4                        & 1988923.289           & \hphantom{Nu}   & Prob $>$ F      & = & 0.0000 \\
 Residual                & 6493440.8             & 245                          & 26503.84              & \hphantom{Nu}   & R-squared     & = & 0.5506\\
 \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.}   & \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.} &    \Vrulefill{-.12in}{.} &\Vrulefill{-.12in}{.}  & \hphantom{Nu}   & Adj R-squared & = & 0.5433\\  
 Total                   & 14449133.96           & 249                      & 58028.6504            & \hphantom{Nu}   & Root MSE      & = & 162.8\\  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you illustrate in picture what do want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why, but the `xhfill` package does the job very simply:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\usepackage{xhfill}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}C{2cm}cccclcr}
 Source & SS & df & MS & \hphantom{Nu} & Number of obs & = & 250 \\
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\xrfill[1.6ex]{1.2pt}} & \hphantom{Nu} & F(5,94) & = & 75.04\\
 Model & 7955693.156 & 4 & 1988923.289 & \hphantom{Nu} & Prob $>$ F & = & 0.0000 \\
 Residual & 6493440.8 & 245 & 26503.84 & \hphantom{Nu} & R-squared & = & 0.5506\\
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\xrfill[1.6ex]{1.2pt}} & \hphantom{Nu} & Adj R-squared & = & 0.5433\\
 Total & 14449133.96 & 249 & 58028.6504 & \hphantom{Nu} & Root MSE & = & 162.8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]